# Is there a limit to how many power armor frames can be obtained?

Tags: fallout-4

In Fallout 4, you can obtain [power armor frames](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Power_armor_frame) (the base for the armor - not the workstation) in a few ways. The ones I know of are:

- Fixed/Quest related ones (such as the ones placed at vertibird crash sites)
- From vendors
- From pickpocketing fusion cores from armored enemies, causing them to step out of their frames

Are any of these sources renewable? If so, which ones?

If they are, I wouldn't feel so bad killing enemies rather than stealing their cores. I basically want to know if *any* of these sources respawn.

Comment: Are you asking if there is a limit to how many power armor frames, or if the power armor pieces respawn?

Comment: Frames. But I guess knowing if the armor pieces are limited is good to know as well.

Comment: It might be worth noting that power armor frames are the working stations where you can modify armor. You can not loot them from enemies, but they can be built from a workshop, with the right perks. I think you are referring to a "full set of power armor" as a frame.

Comment: @Timelord64 I have to disagree. The workstation is called a "Power Armor Station" when you hover over it. What I'm referring to is the "[Power Armor Frame](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Power_armor_frame)". I'll add that distinction to the question. Thank you for the input.

Comment: If thats what it says in game, O stand corrected. Im afk at present so confirmed through wiki

Comment: I just recently had to defend a settlement from an attack by 3 Raiders in Power Armor. Since those are random, I guess the game spawns Power Armors as needed; i.e. they are renewable.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can tell, there's no limit.  You'll find several in the game and can buy frames from certain merchants.

I've left several suits of armor at Sanctuary Hills and they've stayed there throughout the game.

You can also assign companions to wear Power Armor and they'll generally keep it on, even after you dismiss them.

Comment: It looks like you've changed your question after I answered.  Are you asking about Power Armor Frames or Fusion Cores?

Comment: I haven't changed it at all. There's nothing in there indicating I'm asking anything about fusion cores (I merely point out that obtaining power armor frames can be done by pickpocketing the fusion core out of npc's wearing armor)

Comment: The question has not been changed at all. I think it is just very confusing

Comment: @Timelord64 I want to know if there is an unlimited amount of power armor frames in the game or not. I think that came across, but feel free to point out what's confusing about the question.

Comment: I thought the question was fine. To answer your question you could probably collect frames to the point where the game crashes. I know there is an infinite supply of power armor frames provided from enemies that spawn with them if you have the skills to steal the frame from them. Not 100% sure about the merchants but I imagine once the vendor restocks they will restock the frame as well.

Comment: AFAICT companions keep *everything* (not just Power Armor) even after you've dismissed them. Really good to know for when you've got a fully loaded mule with you and end up trading them for the new one you just unlocked. Go find 'em back at home and they'll still have your stuff.

Comment: @Iszi - I've seen companions occasionally take off Power Armor.

Answer (score 5):

Fixed Power Armor locations, such as at Vertibkrds do not respawn, nor do frames in merchant inventories. That said, even between these two sources alone, there are *dozens* of Power Armor frames around the wasteland - you won't run out.

Should you really feel you need *more* power armor, however, power armored enemies such as raiders, Brotherhood of Steel members, and others *will* respawn occasionally, and will also spawn during random encounters such as settlement raids as your game progresses. If you don't mind stealing fusion cores and searching the world a bit, there is a functionally unlimited supply of Power Armor to be had.

Comment: At least _some_ merchant inventories do respawn - I've bought three Power Armor Frames from KLEO in Goodneighbor.

Answer (score 2):

> Are any of these sources renewable? If so, which ones?

In Lexington the raider on the bridge and the one at the top of the fire escape have respawned for me. If they can keep respawning again and again after you clear the area then you could keep stealing their frames as often as they respawn.

Answer (score 0):

I have 36 power armor frames, 10 are from raiders  and marked stolen.  21 are with full sets armor.  Some raider armor respawns and can be stolen if you can get to it before the raiders are alerted and enter it. The rest are empty useable frames.